# Проверка на активный пункт меню js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как проверить- если `.sub ul li a  class="active"` , то сделать `.sub ul display:block` ? после загрузки страницы

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var vmenu = $('#menu > li.sub > .fa-angle-down');
      vmenu.on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('#menu li ul').slideUp();
       if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
           $(this).next().slideUp();
       } else {
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       }
      });

    });
           }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    if($(".sub ul li a").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".sub ul").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: ЕСЛИ там 4 .sub ul то они все открываются, как сделать текущий

Comment: Добавьте текущему элементу уникальный атрибут и проверяйте по нему